# Why has Microsoft locked me out of my computer and how do I login without a "Microsoft account"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-account

I woke up the other day to my computer having rebooted itself for an update which deleted all of the work I had left open from the day before. A blue screen was asking me to do various tasks which I was too busy to do so I dismissed it with the only option that was to "remind me in a few days". There was no option to opt-out.

A few days later there is new a popup at the bottom-right corner of my screen. When trying to dismiss the notification it instead took over my screen. I clicked through a page or two to see what it was about before it told me that to proceed I would be required to attach a "Microsoft account" which I don't have.

I can't close this window with Alt-F4 or kill the process with Ctl-Alt-Del. Task Manager is also blocked as Ctrl-Esc does nothing. There is also no option to dismiss the dialog.

I don't have a Microsoft account. I have an account on this computer and this popup has taken over my screen. I can do a hard reset but this will again destroy the work I have open and for all I know it may popup again when the computer starts up.

Why am I seeing this and how do I dismiss it so that I use the computer that up until now I thought I owned.

Additionally, how can I prevent these kind of intrusive messages from appearing on my computer in the future?

[image]

Comment: Unplug your machine from the internet and reboot, this will get you into your machine, and allow you to get the necessary information to prevent what’s happening and provide it to us

Comment: Do you know what you might have dismissed?  I have a Desktop machine with a local account, has had for 4 years, does all the updates and does not do the above.

Comment: Your work that was open likely was already lost when your machine was rebooted, hopefully, it was saved now it’s just a matter of logging into the machine

Comment: @John This happened after an unexpected "update and reboot" while I was asleep just this past week. It's possible that you haven't gotten this update just yet.

Comment: My machine is completely up to date. There are no outstanding updates and this screen you got does not happen.

Comment: I would have argued that my computer too was up to date with no reminder to reboot later as is usually the case. This event was a complete an unexpected surprise when my monitors came on. I don't turn off my computer at night so this was triggered by an automatic update-and-reboot.